# "This year is 2023. The following year is 2024." — Is it correct to use "the following" here?

Tags: phrase-usage

As far as I understand, if we have a sequence {…, X, Y, …},
then after mentioning X (for example by the phrase "this is X"),
we can already say "the following one is Y".

To check it, I came up with some examples.

---

an example about { the following + "not time" }:

**(1)** *This item is 6. **The next** item is 7*. — I know it's correct

**(2)** *This item is 6. **The following** item is 7*. — I think it's correct too. **Am I right?**

---

an example about { the following + "time" }:

**(3)** *This year is 2023. **Next** year is 2024*. — I know it's correct

**(4)** *This year is 2023. **The following** year is 2024*. — I think it's correct too. **Am I right?**

Comment: It all depends on context. Sometimes, they mean the same thing but they are not always used in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Examples #2 and #4 (with "The following") are correct.  But as the original poster expects, they are not as natural as examples #1 and #3 (with "next").

In the following example, "The following" is more natural.  This is because "next" does not parallelize as well as "following" does:

- Examples #1 and #3 are natural.  The following examples (#2 and #4, respectively) are correct, but not as natural.

Comment: You should repost the sentences so readers do not have to scroll up and down to figure out what you are saying...

Comment: _The following_ is more often used when speaking of the past or future. _I plan to retire at the end of 2026. The following year I hope to visit the USA.)_

Comment: I actually disagree, "following" sounds more natural to me simply because it helps break up a sequence of otherwise very short words. I will agree, however, that this is a very weak preference.